# NullPointerException object and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

```
public class SearchComparison {
    StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
    ArrayUtilities utilities = new ArrayUtilities();

    public void main(String[] args){    
        watch.start();
        utilities.generateRandom(5);
        watch.stop();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run this code but it gives me a NullPointerException error. However, the methods I'm using seem to work fine separately. Can someone help me pointing out my mistake?
Thank you in advance!

Here are the methods in question:

```
public class StopWatch {
    private long startTime;
    private long stopTime;

    public long start(){
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        return startTime;
    }
    public long stop(){
        stopTime = System.nanoTime();
        return stopTime;
    }
}

public class ArrayUtilities {
    public static int[] generateRandom(int n){
        Random r = new Random(1);
        int imax = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int[] array = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            array[i] = r.nextInt(imax);
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter a NPE and need our help, you'll want to indicate to us which line throws the exception. But having said that, you've no static void main method (your current main method isn't static). This code shouldn't even run, much less throw a NPE.

Comment: ... in other words, your main method should be `public static void`

Comment: The stack trace tells you where the NPE came from.  If you don't post a stack trace, we can't help you understand it.

Comment: okay, it gave me an error when i put static in the header. it works if i put the object declaration in the main method. why is that?

Comment: You still haven't posted your NullPointerException stacktrace nor indicated the line which causes the exception. Please complete your question for us before asking a new one.

Comment: actually it is just that missing static in the main method...sorry for bothering you guys.

Comment: Voting to close question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is lack of a modifier **static**

It should be `public static void main(String[] args) {`.

Change your code of class **SearchComparison** as follows and you will get the right result.

```
public class SearchComparison {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
    ArrayUtilities utilities = new ArrayUtilities();
    watch.start();
    utilities.generateRandom(5);
    watch.stop();
}

}
```

The result of one run is as follows:

```
1569548985
215764588
880641847
874970313
446064254
```

Comment: i have a question though, if i put the object declarations in that main method, does it mean that they are declared for the other methods too?